# Failed to create Docker container with Docker Python SDK

Tags: python, docker

The problem is, the Docker container is being created, but it exited immediately, and I do not see anything in the log. Unfortunately I do not see now, what could be the reason for this issue.

The Ubuntu version I am using

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> 
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> uname -a 
Linux ethrbh-VmWare 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 
x86_64 GNU/Linux
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~>
```

Version of the Docker

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~>
```

Commands I issued in the Python3 shell

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~/cee/systemtest/tools/BAT(bat-restart_docker_container_when_docker_engine_restarted)> python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import docker
>>> 
>>> 
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> 
>>> 
>>> client.images.list()
[<Image: 'ubuntu:latest'>, <Image: 'ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6:latest'>, <Image: 'ubuntu:18.04'>, <Image: 'hello-world:latest'>]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> container = client.containers.run(image='ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6',name="myCont",detach=True)
>>> 
>>> container.status
'created'
>>> 
>>> container.status
'created'
>>> container.reload()
>>> container.status
'exited'
>>> 
>>>
```

The status of the created Docker container by the "docker" command in BASH

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> docker ps -a | grep myCont
78e551f7811f        ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6   "/bin/bash"              29 seconds ago      Exited (0) 27 seconds ago                       myCont
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~>
```

I also would like to say, all thing is working as expected (aka Docker container created and kept running) if I do all things in BASH.

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> 
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> docker run -d -it --name myCont2 ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6
4134ebcc683775d27f3241fafaa9052bcb85020af76d23c1da0d22d2ceb4a764
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> 
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> docker ps -a | grep myCont2
4134ebcc6837        ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6   "/bin/bash"              12 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds                                   myCont2
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> 
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> docker ps -a | grep myCont
4134ebcc6837        ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6   "/bin/bash"              15 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds                                   myCont2
78e551f7811f        ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6   "/bin/bash"              9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                        myCont
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~>
```

What did I do wrong, and how to solve it.

Comment: You're running a different command in bash. Try without the `-it` for a comparable command.

Comment: hello BMitch, Thanks for your reply. You are right. I created another container "myCont3" without -it, and the container exited immediately

Looking again the https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html, I think I know what I should do for keep alive the container. I have to use stdin_open=True and tty=True arguments when creating the container.

so thanks for your help
/Robi

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, the stdin_open=True and tty=True arguments should be used when create the Docker container, like this

```
ethrbh@ethrbh-VmWare:~> python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.images.list()
[<Image: 'ubuntu:latest'>, <Image: 'ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6:latest'>, <Image: 'ubuntu:18.04'>, <Image: 'hello-world:latest'>]
>>> container = client.containers.run(image='ubuntu-18_04-cee_st_tools_docker_img-3_6',name="myCont",detach=True, tty=True, stdin_open=True)
>>> container.reload()
>>> container.status
'running'
>>>
```

thanks
/Robi